# Can't find SDK Manager in SDK file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I am being pestered by eclipse when I open the program. I get two error messages; "SDK Platform tools component is missing! ..." and "Failed to get the required ADT version number from the SDK. The Android developer toolkit may not work properly".

Both messages give me the option to open the Android SDK manager. When I attempt to open the Android SDK manager from eclipse, I get an initialization and then nothing happens.

I'm aware this is a common problem. Many solutions say to find the Android SDK manager in the SDK directory, though I can't find it anywhere there. The path I am using is "C:\Users\Ant\AppData\Local\Android\sdk".

When I attempt to open the SDK manager from Android Studio, I get something come up, though I have no idea if it is the Android studio version of the SDK manager or not.

All I want to do is install some packages to get everything running smoothly. I have the feeling that I need to open the SDK manager from eclipse to do it though. Is this correct? Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You should go and create the proper environment setup, It seems there is a confusion between Eclipse and android studio working env. Please make sure to install separately the working env. SDK are normally hidden files make sure you are suppose to see hidden files in your computer.

Thanks,

Ashish